# How to loop through by getting ID dynamically from another tables in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written following code to get data from starting table

```
select * from starting where PID in
( 
select I.InstID from  Inst I,
Trus T where I.TrusID=75 and T.TrusId= 75 and I.InstID = 54 and I.InstStatusID=1 
)
```

Now I want to get "TrusID" and "InstID" dynamically to variable from another tables (lets say "Trus" and "Inst") and pass these as parameter to above query and run in a loop for each "TrusID" and "InstID" I got. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Without context on the bigger problem you're trying to solve, I'll venture an assumption that looping isn't needed.

Assuming the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Trus ([TrusID] int);   
INSERT INTO Trus ([TrusID]) VALUES (75);

CREATE TABLE Inst ([InstID] int, [InstStatusID] int, [TrusID] int); 
INSERT INTO Inst ([InstID], [InstStatusID], [TrusID]) VALUES (54, 1, 75);

CREATE TABLE Starting ([PID] int);  
INSERT INTO Starting ([PID]) VALUES (54);
```

The following SQL produces the same output as your original query:

```
SELECT S.*  
FROM Starting AS S       
INNER JOIN Inst AS I          
    ON S.PID = I.InstID       
INNER JOIN Trus AS T          
    ON I.TrusID = T.TrusID  
WHERE I.InstStatusID = 1;
```

Get in the habit of second guessing yourself if you've arrived at a procedural (loop/cursor) solution to a SQL problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggession. Actully I need to loop through because of some reason.So, Please suggest how to write a loop here. Note that, I have TrusID and InstID already there in another tables.

Comment: @bapi It would be helpful to explain the reason for the looping requirement in your question.

Comment: I'm geeting some more records as per your suggession which is not expected in my case. I need to confirm that with looping.As I feel looping will give me robust answer.